# extjs 4 - get VS select VS query

Tags: extjs4

I am working on ExtJS 4.2 now. There are 3 ways to access DOM elements - get, select, query.

I want to know the difference between them. Why three separate methods?

we have a question here: [SVO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6350693/get-vs-select-vs-query-for-accessing-elements-with-ext-js-framework)

But it doesn't give me any clear answers. Looking for something specific / detailed answer.

Will be grateful if you can help with the explanation.

Thanks in advance :-)

EDIT based on answer below:

I am not much into jQuery so can't understand through comparison. Can anyone help me with the difference between an Ext.element and a composite element?

EDIT 2:

What is Ext.dom.Element? Any different from Ext.element? and if anyone could throw some light on "Ext.fx.Anim" package?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### [`Ext.get`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext-method-get)

`Ext.get` is analogous to `document.getElementById` in that you can provide the ID of a DOM node and retrieve that element wrapped as `Ext.dom.Element`.  You can also provide a DOM node or an existing Element.

```
// Main usage: DOM ID
var someEl = Ext.get('myDivId');

// Wrap a DOM node as an Element
var someDom = document.getElementById('myDivId');
someEl = Ext.get(someDom);

// Identity function, essentially
var sameEl = Ext.get(someEl);
```

### [`Ext.query`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.dom.Query-method-select)

`Ext.query` allows you to select an array of DOM nodes using CSS/XPath selectors. This is handy when working with custom components or data views and you need a more robust selection mechanism than DOM IDs.

```
// Get all DOM nodes with class "oddRow" that are children of
// my component's top-level element.
var someNodes = Ext.query('.oddRow', myCustomComponent.getEl().dom);
```

### [`Ext.select`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext-method-select)

`Ext.select` is essentially Ext JS's answer to jQuery's selectors. Given some CSS/XPath selector, it returns a single object representing a collection of Elements. This [`CompositeElement`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.dom.CompositeElement) has methods for filtering, iterating, slicing the collection.

Most importantly, the `CompositeElement` supports chainable versions of **all** methods of `Ext.dom.Element` and `Ext.fx.Anim` that operate on each element in the collection, making this method very powerful.

**Edit 1**: An `Ext.Element` represents a single DOM node, while an `Ext.dom.CompositeElement` represents a collection of DOM nodes that can be affected through a single interface. So, given the following example:

```
// Set the height of each table row using Ext.query
var tableRowNodes = Ext.query('tr', document.getElementById('myTable'));
Ext.Array.each(tableRowNodes, function (node) {
    Ext.fly(node).setHeight(25);
});

// Set the height of each table row using Ext.select
var compositeEl = Ext.select('#myTable tr');
compositeEl.setHeight(25);
```

You can see how much easier it is to work with `Ext.dom.CompositeElement`.

**Edit 2**: Ext JS supports the concept of alternate class names. Think of them as shortcuts for commonly used classes. `Ext.Element` is the alternate class name for `Ext.dom.Element` and can be used interchangeably.

[`Ext.fx.Anim`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.fx.Anim) is a class representing an animation. Usually not used directly, it is created behind the scenes when performing animations on elements or components. For example, the first parameter of `Ext.Component#hide` is the animation target.

Comment: 1: Does Ext.query return array of DOM nodes or Ext.Element objects? If it is the first one, then how to convert this array of DOM nodes into array of Ext.Element objects IN ONE PASS?

Comment: The answer is in the docs, it says it returns `HTMLElement[]`. So, the former. If you want to get a collection, then use `Ext.select`.

Comment: I forgot to mention this in my answer, but `Ext.fly` creates a temporary `Ext.Element` around a DOM node.

Comment: Where is this in the official tutorial? Very helpful, thank you!